# Process.start in c#, not firing

Tags: c#

I am trying to create some files using fsutil, but no files are getting created with the following loop, neither is an error getting generated, any suggestions?

```
foreach (string extension in extensions)
{
   Process.Start("fsutil", @"file createnew e:\attachments\" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + extension); 
}
```

Comment: Your application has administrative privileges, I take it?

Comment: Sure, running as my logged on admin account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateTime.Now.ToString() might be returning spaces and characters that aren't allowed in filenames. Try quoting the filename for the argument string and replacing any colons with underscores, or the like. FSUTIL also requires the length of the file to be specified, as ArsenMkrt stated.

```
Usage : fsutil file createnew <filename> <length>
   Eg : fsutil file createnew C:\testfile.txt 1000
```

Comment: Basically, just make sure your resulting filename is allowed by the operating system by removing/replacing characters that aren't allowed, and you'll be fine and dandy. =)